# If we don't care about uniqueness, can we relax the coercivity condition in Lax-Milgram theorem?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, hilbert-spaces

Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and $\|\cdot \|$ its induced norm. Let $a: H \times H \to \mathbb R$ be a bilinear form. We say that

- $a$ is *coercive* IFF there is $C>0$ such that $a(u, u) \ge C \|u \|^2$.
- $a$ is *continuous* IFF there is $C>0$ such that $|a(u, v)| \le C \|u \| \|v \|$.

Lax–Milgram theorem says that if $a$ is a continuous coercive bilinear form on $H$, then for each $\varphi \in H^*$ there is a unique $u \in H$ such that
$$
a(u, v) = \varphi (v),
\quad \forall v \in H.
$$

> Assume that we only want the existence and not necessarily the uniqueness. Can we relax any of above assumtions?

My question arises when I look for the solution of Sturm–Liouville problem $-(pU')' + qU = f$ with a boundary condition of only one endpoint, i.e.,

> Let $I$ be the open interval $(0, 1)$. Assume that $p \in C^1(\bar I)$ and $q \in$ $C(\bar I)$ such that $p(x) \geq \alpha \in \mathbb R_{>0}$ and $q(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \bar I$. Let $f \in L^2 (I)$. We want to find $U \in H^1(I)$ such that $U(0)=1$ and that for each $V \in C_c^\infty (I)$,
> $$
> \int_I pU' V' + \int_I qUV = \int_I fV.
> $$

Comment: This looks like trying to kill a fly with a sledgehammer. If you have only one boundary condition, cannot you just complement it arbitrarily to from a full set of initial conditions, and use existence and uniqueness for the IVP? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy You are right! I was being stupid :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more suited for math.SE but I'll still post the answer here, although the post will likely be closed soon.
You can simply apply Lax-Milgram in the Hilbert space
$$
H=\Big\{f\in H^1(0,1): \qquad f(0)=0\Big\}
$$
equipped with the usual norm
$$
\|f\|:=\int_0^1 |f'|^2.
$$
With the left boundary condition $f(0)=0$ this is clearly equivalent to the full $H^1$ norm due to Poincaré's inequality.
Looking for a solution in the form $U(x)=1+u(x)$ your problem is clearly equivalent to solving
$$
\begin{cases}
-(pu')'+q u =g
\\
u(0)=0
\end{cases}
\qquad \text{with }g=f-q\in L^2.
$$
Then the bilinear form $a(u,v)=\int p u'v'$ is continuous, $\alpha$-coercive, and the linear form $\phi(v)=\int gv$ is clearly continuous.
This gives uniqueness altogether.